# Filter maximum value and corresponding date based on the country time series data using group by?

Tags: python, pandas, python-2.7, pandas-groupby

I'm trying to find which day has the maximum number of new cases and group-by country. The dataset contains the list of country time-series data with the number of COVID total cases, new cases, new test ect.

[image]

Expected output

```
Country    Date Cases      MaxNew_Cases
USA        2020-06-23      1988
Singapore  2020-05-21      456
Franch     2020-03-12      765
```

I've tried:

```
df_test_date.loc[df_test_date['new_cases'].idxmax()]
df1=df_test_date[['location','date']][df_test_date.new_cases == df_test_date['new_cases'].max()]
new_df = df_test_date.groupby('location')['Log_New_Cases'].max()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
data = {
    'Country': ['USA', 'Singapore', 'France', 'USA', 'Singapore', 'France', 'USA', 'Singapore', 'France'],
    'Date': ['2020-06-01', '2020-06-01', '2020-06-01', '2020-06-02', '2020-06-02', '2020-06-02', '2020-06-03', '2020-06-03', '2020-06-03'],
    'New_Cases': [100, 200, 300, 600, 500, 400, 123, 345, 523]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
idxmax = df.groupby('Country')['New_Cases'].idxmax()
df.iloc[idxmax]
```

Data Frame

```
     Country        Date  New_Cases
0        USA  2020-06-01        100
1  Singapore  2020-06-01        200
2     France  2020-06-01        300
3        USA  2020-06-02        600
4  Singapore  2020-06-02        500
5     France  2020-06-02        400
6        USA  2020-06-03        123
7  Singapore  2020-06-03        345
8     France  2020-06-03        523
```

Output

```
     Country        Date  New_Cases
8     France  2020-06-03        523
4  Singapore  2020-06-02        500
3        USA  2020-06-02        600
```